# Do we need separate tags for antivirus and antimalware?

Tags: discussion, tags

[antivirus](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antivirus) is a subset of [antimalware](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antimalware).

Is there really a need to distinguish between the two when for all intents and purposes, they are referring to tools to protect a system from malware?

Comment: Intuitively, I think they *should* be the same, but in reality they're NOT. Products of each work in very different ways, they fit different environments, e.g. AV is often a regulatory requirement, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Turning my comment to an answer):

Intuitively, I too think they should be the same, but in reality they're NOT.
Products of each work in very different ways, they fit different environments, e.g. AV is often a regulatory requirement.

So syntactically, you would be right it is a subset, but the actual products are not.

Bottom line, while in theory, there should be no difference between the two, but in practice there is.

Answer (score 1):

Well the 'virus' is something you'll hardly see these days. However the rootkit, trojan, worm, spyware and adware are common to see.

A virus, (real virus) can replicate himself to other programs and is memory resilient. What you see commonly is a worm that weaponized an exploit and spreads over the networks.

But, this is kinda off topic.
I'd recommend to just use Anti-Malware.  As Virus is an outdated term most of the time.

### Don't trust my word on it, trust Wikipedia

A computer virus is a computer program that can replicate itself and spread from one computer to another.[1] The term "virus" is also commonly, but erroneously, used to refer to other types of malware, including but not limited to adware and spyware programs that do not have a reproductive ability.

Comment: "memory resilient" what do you mean?

Comment: Doesn't have it's own 'body'. It infects other files (exe, com, elf) and injects it's code. Most often (in old viruses) it finds the EntryPoint, changes the first instruction to a jmp to the end of the code. Pastes it's code and finsishes with the first code on the EntryPoint and adds a jump back. 

When you get the newer viruses you'll detect Metamophic stuff and packers that pack other executables. A virus is 'hard' to detect or delete by hand. Where a 'netcat backdoor' is not.

Answer (score 0):

I would just put them up as synonyms.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down. I think Lucas is right.

Comment: +1, the average computer user doesn't know or care what the difference is and will call any manner of malware a virus by default.  It's the default pariah.  "Why didn't you bring your laptop to class today?"  "It's not working.  I got a virus."